# Do I have too much query tabs open in Teradata causing spool error?

Tags: sql, teradata

I was trying to run top 10* from a table. I could normally do that, but not this time. I do have a lot of Teradata screens open. Do you think that's using up the spool space? Thank you!

Comment: Probably not, only sessions with active queries will consume spool (and sessions with Volatile Tables). Did this Select include Where/Joins/Order By?

Comment: yes, there're a lot of joins and where. It is also a volatile table. (what does it mean? Can I modify it?) Thank you

Comment: The TOP option is the last step before a final Order By, but after anyWhere/Group By/Having/etc., i.e. the full answer set is created *first* and then the Top is applied (check Explain). Additionally a Volatile (=Temporary) Table is stored in spool, thus reducing the available spool space. A possible workaround is to apply the Top (or Sample) on one of the tables before the joins by wrapping it in a Derived Table.

Comment: Look out for Skew. If your data distribution is highly uneven, you may run out of spool on one AMP, while the others still have a lot, but the query can't complete. This tends to happen, for example if you have a lot of null values in a column used in a join. The resulting spool table on one AMP may be too big then.